# Close and open new modal by clicking a link

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have two modals created with bootstrap - one for sign in and one for sign up. In each modal I have a link which I want it to refer to the other modal. E.g the sign up modal is open, registered users can click a link inside the sign up modal in order to sign in, and vice versa. 
How can I close the sign up div when clicking the sign in link and open the sign in div instead?

complete code in here:

https://jsfiddle.net/f9r3ttpw/

This is the example starting code for the sign up modal:

```
<div class="modal modal-backdrop fade" id="myModalJoin" tabindex="-1"
            role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-contentJoin">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
     label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></button>
    <h2 class="modal-title join" id="myModalLabel"></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
```

Comment: You'll need to manually instantiate your modals and close/open events. Take a look at [the Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript).

Comment: I am not very good at Jquery/JavaScript. Any chance you'll send me the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Here is working code

**Java script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#myModal2").modal('show');
  });


  $("#login").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    $("#myModal2").modal('show');
  });


  $("#singup").click(function(){
    $("#myModal2").modal('hide');
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
  });

});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
    <a href="#" id="btn1" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">sign up</a> <a href="#" id="btn2" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">login</a>

    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Sign up code here?</p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    <button type="button" id="login" class="btn btn-primary">login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Login code here?</p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    <button type="button" id="singup" class="btn btn-primary">sign up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap has option to open and hide modal window. You just need to call methods properly For example

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(".modal1.show").click(function(){
    $("#myModal2").modal('hide');
});
```

$(".modal2.show").click(function(){

$("#myModal1").modal('hide');
    });

});

Comment: I see, but how can I initialize the show/hide functions while clicking on a link? And where should i put that <script> tag - On the head or in the footer?

Comment: Thanks. 
In your example modal1.show refers to the open modal and #myModal2 refers to the link I click in order to hide the open modal and open the new modal?

Comment: Dear Manish Shukla, thank you for your help, I succeseed. One thing is missing though, please advise:
When in sign in page, clicking a link, the sign in page become hidden and the sign up page is shown - this is exactly how i wanted it to be. The problem is that after doing this hide/show, when in sign up modal and clicking the link, It just hide the sign up modal instead of hide it and show the sign in modal. I think i need a loop but don't know quite how to do so. Please advise

Comment: If you can give me code snippet then i will be able to help you with more details

Comment: Thank you, Currently on my way to work, so I will do so in the evening and update

Comment: Hi Manish Shukla, I added a Fiddle of the 3 modals. Can you please see?
https://jsfiddle.net/6ka625pL/1/

What I want to do is this:
1. When sign in modal is open and user clicks on "forgot password" - close the sign in modal and open the forgot password modal.
2. When sign in modal is open and user clicks on "NotAMember link" - close the sign in modal and open the sign up modal modal.
3. When sign up modal is open and user clicks on "RegisteredMember link" - close the sign up modal and open the sign in modal.
4. I only succeed to close the sign in modal and open the sign up modal but no loop

Comment: Hi Manish Shukla, any suggestions?